Laravel 11 reverb connection using rest api and custom auth giving 403 forbidden
I am using laravel 11 in my web application. I am trying to implement reverb connection between my laravel 11 and react front end using rest api. The websocket connection seems established but the broadcasting/auth always returning 403 Forbidden. I am using my custom authentication named simple_auth.
I routes\api.php I have added this line,
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['simple_auth']]);

Where simple_auth is my custom alias to my custom authentication which is based on Bearer token. I have a subdomain for my api which is api.abc.test
In frontend echo.js
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: 'sdfsdfsdfkjmvedvs',
    authorizer: channel => {
        console.log(channel)
        return {
            authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('socket_id', socketId);
                formData.append('channel_name', channel.name);
                axios
                    .post('http://api.abc.test/broadcasting/auth', formData, {
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": 'Bearer 4eXzQ4TYARrsDMCV3IN8AI0pKI4Klu7DeJssJNgDF1hG8C4V5HGKgQvquBlWoJNRhKlb5c37xgeNApAFlPNaL5E7NMQ456464654654sdfsdfsdfpKmJiXhuMs3V2OLgCizAjCIRnzBmA0HUzzfd8Kc7Yr4UqqMLzIxz6cbvcbcvbdr45454545FEnblBeG2rgyDCWqync9dLVSoZvx8n2fOU1Fp7HUyUTI6Cz2EhfWxoZlQ0',
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                        },
                        withCredentials: true,
                        withXSRFToken: true,
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        callback(false, response.data)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        callback(true, error)
                    })
            },
        }
    },
    wsHost: 'api.abc.test',
    wsPort: 8080 ?? 80,
    wssPort: 8080 ?? 443,
    forceTLS: ('http' ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

Since it is not a sactum, I am not sending csrf token with it. I am not sure csrf is the reason for 403 Forbidden.
While I am trying I am always getting 403 forbidden. Kindly note I am using my custom auth, I am not using sanctum library.
Let me know if you have further clarifications.

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: 'sdfsdfsdfkjmvedvs',
    authorizer: channel => {
        return {
            authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('socket_id', socketId);
                formData.append('channel_name', channel.name);
                axios
                    .post('http://abc.test/broadcasting/auth', formData, {
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": 'Bearer YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN',
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                        },
                        withCredentials: true,
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        callback(false, response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        callback(true, error);
                    });
            },
        };
    },
    wsHost: 'abc.test',
    wsPort: 8080 ?? 80,
    wssPort: 8080 ?? 443,
    forceTLS: ('http' ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});


Yes, everything configured correctly. Even the middleware working properly. After passing the middleware I am getting 403 Forbidden. I don't know what I have missed

shared code another sol.

I am using the same code and tried so many times but no luck. Everything passes fine but only the auth keeps on saying Forbidden

In your channel declaration pass 3ed parameter to spicify guards
['guards '=>['sanctum']]

